# How can I import data from excel to MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, excel

I tried to import the data from excel to MYSQL by using the following command:

```
  load data local infile "filepath" into table mytab;
```

But this command is work for import the data from text file not for csv file or xlsx. I want to import the data directly from excel to MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

check following,
see the seperator in your csv file and make sure you provide the correct one in command.
[Referance Link](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
load data local infile "filepath" into table mytab fields terminated by ';' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

Should be the command you need, but you should export to csv first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your Excel sheet into a CSV file, or use [MySQL for Excel](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/) to help with the process.